# How to get properties in VideoModeDescriptor through WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to get the Monitor properties in C#. I use the WMI to get the information I need.
Currently I can get correct PNPID from Win32_DesktopMonitor and compare with the result of InstanceName from WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes.
Then I want to get detail information of the monitor by VideoModeDescriptor. Here are my codes below, but I always get the fail as "invalid query" of scherDM2c.Get().
May I know what kind of mistake I made?

```cs
private void MonitorBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcherM = new ManagementObjectSearcher($"SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor Where Name Like '%{MonitorBox.Text}%'");

            foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcherM.Get())
            {
                dMaker.Text = wmi.GetPropertyValue("MonitorManufacturer").ToString();
                dID.Text = wmi.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID").ToString();
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcherDM2a = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\wmi", "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes");

                foreach (ManagementObject sbu_wmi in searcherDM2a.Get())
                {
                    string WMIID = sbu_wmi.GetPropertyValue("InstanceName").ToString();

                    if (WMIID.ToUpper().Contains(dID.Text.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        ManagementObjectSearcher scherDM2c = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\wmi", $"SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes Where InstanceName Like %{WMIID}%");
                        //ManagementObjectCollection MColl = scherDM2c.Get();


                        foreach (ManagementObject ModeList in scherDM2c.Get())
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(ModeList.GetPropertyValue("HorizontalActivePixels").ToString());
                        }
                        
                        /*listBox1.Items.Add(sbu_wmi.GetPropertyValue("PreferredMonitorSourceModeIndex").ToString());
                        var i = sbu_wmi.GetPropertyValue("PreferredMonitorSourceModeIndex").ToString();
                        listBox1.Items.Add(sbu_wmi.GetPropertyValue("MonitorSourceModes").ToString());*/
                    }
                }

                /*listBox1.Items.Add(wmi.GetPropertyValue("CreationClassName").ToString());
                listBox1.Items.Add(wmi.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString());
                listBox1.Items.Add(wmi.GetPropertyValue("MonitorType").ToString());*/
            }
        }
```

Comment: OK,  forget about it. I use ManagementBaseObject to get the information I need...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,You forgot to add ''

```
ManagementObjectSearcher scherDM2c = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\wmi", $"SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorListedSupportedSourceModes Where InstanceName Like '%{WMIID}%'");
```